# matplotlib package cannot import with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

when I installed TensorFlow, I successfully imported it to my jupyter notebook. But when I try to import matplotlib.pyplot  package, it says 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'  but for NumPy packages, it imports without a problem. I tried it in various ways but failed. Please, who knows why matplotlib cannot be imported?

Comment: Please say more about how you did the install and your system. What version of Python? Are you using any virtual environments? Did you do use `pip` or `conda` or something else to install?

Comment: @adamconkey Thanks for your reply,  'conda info --envs'  shows # base

Comment: Okay you're using `conda`. In that case, do command `conda list` and update your question with the output.

Comment: @adamconkey Thanks for your reply,  'conda info --envs'  shows # base,  py3-TF2.0, tensorflow,  tensorflow_env.  I used following commands on anaconda promts:  conda create --name py3-TF2.01 python=3, then  conda activate py-TF2.01. Then pip install --upgrade tensorflow, here it says ' can't find a version that satisfy'. then  pip install ipykernel.  Next, I go to jupyter and choose py3-TF2.01. Once I tried to import tensorflow, numpy and matplotlib, again matplotlib cannot be imported. One more thing, on the top enter 'kernel' and then 'change kernel', there's only 'python 3' there, no others

Comment: conda list   ->  many packages  including  'matplotlib 3.1.1  py37hc8f65d3_0'

Comment: It's very likely your pip install of tensorflow is messing things up. Why not do `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`.

Comment: Adam, I just followed a tutorial on udemy. Would you suggest unstalling all and intalling differently? I'd be grateful to you if you give a hint that works or any useful instructional link.  I got stuck on this issue the whole day.

Comment: @adamconkey When I followed your advice, it has been fixed. Thanks you saved me!!!

Comment: Glad to hear it, in the meantime I was writing up an answer. If it addresses your problem adequately please consider marking as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that mixing `conda` and `pip` is causing some issues, and it is [recommended](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) when using conda to try to leverage conda packages as much as possible. You can try a full `conda` install and see if it works:

```
conda create -n tf
conda activate tf
conda install tensorflow matplotlib notebook
```

With this setup I was able to immediately start `jupter notebook`, create a new notebook and import both `tensorflow` and `matplotlib` successfully.